# Inserting input type file into mySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, html, servlets

I want to insert the photoPath URL that the servlet gets from the form into my table however, it is not working.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String number = request.getParameter("contactNumber");
    String position = request.getParameter("position");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String photoPath = request.getParameter("myImage");

    MySqlHandler.registerEmployee(name, number, position, email, photoPath);

}
```

If I do

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println(photoPath);
    }
```

the url is displayed as 150x150.png (which is the name of my img) so I know the string is stored there. But when I pass it into my registerEmployee function, it stops all data from getting inserted into my table. If I set photoPath to some static string, everything gets inserted properly. What could be wrong? I think maybe the string I get from

```
request.getParameter("myImage");
```

contains some weird characters that can't be inserted into mysql table?

```
  public static void registerEmployee(String name, String number, String position, String email, String photoPath) {
  initConnection();

  try {
      String query = " insert into employee_registry (name, number, position, email, photo_path)"
              + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
      preparedStatement.setString(2, number);
      preparedStatement.setString(3, position);
      preparedStatement.setString(4, email);
      preparedStatement.setString(5, photoPath);
      preparedStatement.execute();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
  }

  closeConnection();
}
```

Form

```
<form action="" id="registerForm" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Register Now</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Full Name: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input name="name" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="error-wrapper">
                        <div class="hideError"> Field is blank </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Position: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input name="position" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="error-wrapper">
                        <div class="hideError"> Field is blank </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Email: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input name="email" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="error-wrapper">
                        <div class="hideError"> Field is blank </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Contact Number: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input name="contactNumber" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="error-wrapper">
                        <div class="hideError"> Field is blank </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Photos: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="photo-wrapper">
                        <input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="error-wrapper">
                        <div class="hideError"> Field is blank </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you not get any errors?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to check that the vars like `name` all have values? You could also try hard-coding some values.

Comment: If i just pass a string to replace the last parameter of the registerEmployee function, everything is inserted into table as should. it's just when I want to get the URL from the input type file, it does not work